# Why I cannot create pipenv shell in ubuntu 20.04 LTS with python3.8?

Tags: 20.04, python3, heroku, pipenv

I am getting following error while creating executing `pipenv shell` command:

```
⠋/usr/bin/python3: No module named pipenv.pew

Virtualenv location: 
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 571, in shell
    core.do_shell(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2093, in do_shell
    ensure_project(three=three, python=python, validate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 636, in ensure_project
    ensure_pipfile(validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 289, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 518, in create_pipfile
    'python_version': python_version(required_python)[: len('2.7')]
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

For hosting on heroku I require pipenv shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04, but since you are on heroku I am not sure if you can execute these but, in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pipenv
sudo pip3 install pipenv (or sudo pip install pipenv)
```

After that I had another problem with the version of virtualenv. For that I removed python3-virtualenv and the version of virtualenv installed by pip

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-virtualenv
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

You can check, if pipenv works:
/home/[your_username]/.local/bin/pipenv

If you still face a problem with virtualenv, look here:
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues

After it works, add /home/[your_user]/.local/bin/ to your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Some it's the case when you need to add path to your binaries. like adding `/home/<username>/.local/bin` to you $PATH.

use this to add it.

```bsh
PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"
```

Comment: I had a same error. "NoneType object not subscriptable".  pipenv command try to search in `usr/bin/pipenv` where `pipenv` file is not present even if I install using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be due to permission issues.
I run `sudo pipenv shell` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no Python 2 installed and no python executeable in my PATH. To fix this, I created a simbolic link:

```
# find location of python3
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

# create link from python to python3 in the original directory
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score -1):

I think is better that you use python3-venv instead of pipenv

you can install with below code

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

and create a virtualenv with:

```
python3 -m venv <folder name for virtualenv>
```

and active it with:

```
source <folder name for virtualenv>/bin/activate
```

and deactivate with:

```
deactivate
```

you can use python3.8 instead of python3(Especially when another version of Python is installed on your system)

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks its working, but for hosting I require pipenv.